# Need help to remove html tags from a link

Tags: php, clickable

Code:

```
$message = "<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\" target=\"new\">My link</a>";

function unclick ($message) {
$message = preg_replace("#\<a.+href\=[\"|\'](.+)[\"|\'].*\>.*\<\/a\>#U","$1",$message);
$message = str_replace("mailto:","",$message);
return $message;
}
```

this works only when link looks like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work for longer links:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Need a way to remove html tags from all links. Thanks.

Comment: That's what [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) is for.

Comment: he doesn't want to strip tag he wants the href="`value`"

Comment: If that's the case, the question title and explanation are utterly useless.

Comment: @ceeya: couldn't agree more +1

Comment: Is your hoped for output `"My link"` or `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask "`?

Answer (score 1):

Of course How we cannot post the bobince mighty answer:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If you need to parse HTML you may want to use the `DOMDocument`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine for me.

Another solution:

Must this be done in PHP, or can you use JavaScript with jQuery?

According to your title:

```
yourlink.removeAttr('href');
```

According to what your code does:

```
var url = yourlink.attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<?php
$input = '<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/hello/hi/bye">hello</a>';
$sx = simplexml_load_string($input);
echo ($sx['href']);
?>
</pre>
```

Try this. its working properly if the url is not `escaped with \`
if it is escaped then use this script:

```
<pre>
<?php
$input = '<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com/hello/hi/bye\">hello</a>';
$input = str_replace('\\','',$input);
$sx = simplexml_load_string($input);
echo ($sx['href']);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: $input may contain not only 1 link. It may contain texts and many links. I need to remove html tags from all links leaving just plain URL.